# Creating a method for my quiz in C#

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to create a method in my quiz program that will evaluate a users answers for different questions.

I am currently using a `do...while` loop with an `if...else` statement in every question, but I would like to transfer all that into its own method that I can invoke in each question in order to clean everything up.

This is what I currently have:

```
public static void CurrentQuestion(string userAnswer, string correctAnswer)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    do
    {
        if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
            break;
        }
        else if (userAnswer != correctAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input");
        }
    }
    while ((userAnswer != "A") || (userAnswer != "B") || (userAnswer != "C") || (userAnswer != "D"));
}
```

And the place where I invoke it:

```
CurrentQuestion("", "D");
```

The problem I having now is that when I run the program on the console and I input an answer it always tells me that it is incorrect. I am not sure what it wrong with the code, or what I need to do to get it to work properly.

I would also like to be able to differentiate between lower case and upper case and letters that aren't A, B, C, or D when inputing an answer if possible, but I'm currently just trying to get it to work properly first.

Comment: You're using `Console.ReadLine()` but not storing the response

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, this method is meant to return whether "userAnswer" equals "correctAnswer".  Yes?

Comment: Your `else` isn't reachable because either `userAnswer == correctAnswer` or `userAnswer != correctAnswer`; what third possibility is there?

Comment: Console.Readline() returns the value written by the user, after he hits the "Enter" key. But where in your program are you using this value ?
You should write something like `string theAnswerWrittenByUser = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: I assume the goal of your `Console.ReadLine()` is to read user input? If so, since the purpose of `CurrentQuestion()` seems to be to evaluate if the answer user entered is the correct answer, your `Console.ReadLine()` should be outside the method. Also, you need to take that input into a string variable, and then pass it as the first parameter.

Comment: OK, reading through again, seems to me that the objective is to keep prompting the user to enter either `A, B, C, or D` like a multiple choice question, and once done, output whether correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for everyones hasty responses. I set the `Console.ReadLine()` to a variable in order to store the result and placed it inside the loop of the method I am creating. It works now. Properly evaluates the users inputs as incorrect or correct based on what I set. The last else statement is supposed to be if someone selects anything else other than `A, B, C, or D` such as @Sach said, but I am unsure how to set that up. My original loop that I had for every question worked out because I set the values individually per question. Now the method is making it a little trickier to figure out.

Comment: @ChadMitchell check out my answer. It should resolve your loop problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First, as several people have pointed out in the comments, you're not storing the results of `Console.ReadLine()`.

Secondly, your `else` statement isn't reachable. Think about it: either `userAnswer == correctAnswer` or it doesn't. What third choice is there?

Third, this is trivially always true:

```
(userAnswer != "A") || (userAnswer != "B") || (userAnswer != "C") || (userAnswer != "D")
```

Think about it - if `userAnswer == "A"`, then obviously `userAnswer != "B"`. This means that this is an infinite loop.

I think that you meant to use `&&` here. This would mean "keep looping until the user enters either "A", "B", "C", or "D"".

You may also want to check out [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which are exceptionally useful for cases like this.

Fourth, there's no way to change `userAnswer` because you never change it anywhere in code. Even your `Console.ReadLine()` is outside the loop (and besides, it doesn't do anything anyway because it doesn't store the result).

To simplify this, you could simply use [ternary form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
string output = userAnswer == correctAnswer ? "That is correct" : "Sorry, that's incorrect";
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Ok, so I changed all the `||` to `&&` and set the `Console.ReadLine()` to a variable inside the loop. It now evaluates the users answer as correct or incorrect. But it still doesn't loop if the user selects anything different that "A", "B", "C" or "D". Thats my next problem to tackle, but at least it correctly evaluates my answers now. Thank you!

Comment: @ChadMitchell Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test that the user types A or B or C or D

```
(userAnswer != "A") || (userAnswer != "B") || (userAnswer != "C") || (userAnswer != "D")
```

IS wrong. This is always true. If they type A then `!= B` is true and so the whole thing is true (given the `or`s).  You want.

```
(userAnswer != "A") && (userAnswer != "B") && (userAnswer != "C") && (userAnswer != "D")
```

This is an example where common human english doesnt match programming english

Comment: indeed - i just pulled it out and clarified a little

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by @EJoshuaS is a very good answer. This is another way of 'fixing' your code to achieve the end result.

First, it looks like when calling the method you want to get the user input inside the method. Therefor, making`userAnswer` a parameter of the method and then passing an empty string when calling the method is redundant. You can get rid of the parameter altogether and simply pass only the `correctAnswer`.

Next, I assume the intended usage of the `while` loop is to keep prompting the user to enter either A, B, C, or D in case something else is entered. So I would use `do-while(true)`, as follows, and if the input is none of A, B, C, or D, prompt the user to enter it again. Once a correct value is entered, evaluate it.

```
public static void CurrentQuestion(string correctAnswer)
{

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter answer: ");
        string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

        if ((userAnswer != "A") && (userAnswer != "B") && (userAnswer != "C") && (userAnswer != "D"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Not a Valid Input");
        }
        else
        {
            if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat is correct!");
                break;
            }
            else if (userAnswer != correctAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, that is incorrect");
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Explanation:
First time, inside the `do-while` loop, the user is asked to enter the answer. Then we check if it's one of A, B, C, o D. If not, print the `Invalid Input` message, and do another iteration of the loop. If it *is* one of the expected four answers, we evaluate it and print either "Correct" or "Incorrect" and exit the loop.

Call it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string correctAnswer = "D";
    CurrentQuestion(correctAnswer);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```